# Failed to remote login windows azure remote desktop

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I am running SQL Server 2012 Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on windows azure. I can remote login from my laptop. But when I'm tring to login from my desktop it says :-

Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

I can't figure out what's the problem .

Comment: That is the standard error message you get when the machine is not reachable/accessible. Make sure your RDP end point is open And the VM is running. By any chance if your desktop is XP! You will not be able to access it via RD due to security, but the error message you get is a different one.

Comment: I'm running windows8 on my desktop as well as in my laptop also.Is it necessary to install azure sdk to connect azure virtual machine. I've installed on my laptop but not on my desktop.By the way end point is always open and also VM is running perfectly.

Comment: you don't need to install any SDK to access the VM via RD. Did you check the firewall setting of your desktop whether it is allowed to make any RD connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys I found the solution. It was `Norton Internet Security` which was blocking the port 3389. Then I found a solution here : http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/issue-windows-7-remote-desktop-2010-internet-security#comment-3515591

Followed these steps :
To get get remote desktop to work with NIS 2010 you need to open NIS then click Settings  in the Network part of the GUI. 
You then under Smart Firewall you Click on Configure On Advanced Settings.
Then on General Rules Click Configure. Then ADD Select Allow and then next and Select Connections to and From other computers. 
Then Click Next under what Computers leave at Any and select Next.
Then Select the Type of port and select Only Communications that match all types and ports listed below: and then Click Add to add the port you need to select Individually specified ports as Remote desktop isn't listed as a port.
And enter the port 3389 you need to add it for both Local and Remote.
Once both Local and Remote are in there click next.
Select Log and or NAT traversal and click next.
Name the Rule you made click next and Finish if it looks correct.
Then Click OK to close all the NIS windows and it will now allow Remote desktop connection throught NIS 2010

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy or firwall might disabled the port  3389 which is used for RDP...
And try to ping the url(http://yourRole.cloudapp.net) of your server from the desktop...